# Animation inside the div only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

i have a circle animation within a button but i want the animation to stay inside the button and not overlap it. Is this possible?

here is my code. and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xumbrpa4/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('button').on("mouseup",function(){
            $('#mousemark').removeClass("click");
        });

        $('button').on('click', function(e){
            $('#mousemark').css({
               left:  e.pageX,
               top:  e.pageY
            });
            $('#mousemark').addClass("click");
        });

    })
```

Comment: You may wanna set a `overflow:hidden` to your container div.

Comment: set button position to relative and overflow:hidden

Comment: Try adding `position: relative;` and `overflow: hidden;` to `button` element

Comment: Argh I feel so stupid thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `position:relative` and `overflow:hidden` to the button:

Check the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xumbrpa4/2/)

```
button {
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    margin:40px;
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```